# Geometric mean and standard deviation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

standard deviation (std) can be used when arithmetic mean is the right statistic. What is the equivalent of std when geometric mean is the right statistic?

Comment: Can you provide more information on the problem you are trying to consider? As stated, it lacks enough detail to answer adequately.

Comment: [Geometric standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_standard_deviation)

Answer (score 2):

The geometric mean can be motivated by noting that it is the exponent of the arithmetic mean of the logarithm:

$$\overline{x}_{geo}=\left(\prod_{i}x_{i}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=exp\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}log(x_{i})\right]=exp\left[\overline{log(x)}\right]$$

So it makes sense to take the exponent of the standard deviations of the logs as the equivalent measure:

$$s_{x,geo}=exp\left[s_{log(x)}\right]=exp\left[\sqrt{\overline{\{log(x)\}^{2}}-\{\overline{log(x)}\}^{2}}\right]$$

Where:
$$\overline{log(x)}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}log(x_{i})$$
$$\overline{\{log(x)\}^{2}}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}[log(x_{i})]^2$$

However, in a particular context, better estimates of error may be more appropriate in a specific modeling context, such as the (observed) fisher information.